# Android Gradle No Rebuild Dependency Except For One Module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Here's the dependency graph of my android app:

app
|---- module1
|--------- hugeModule
|---- module2
|--------- hugeModule

`app` depends on `module1` and `module2` which both of them depends on `hugeModule`.

I am working on feature in `module2`. When I want to test them out, I want to force gradle not to rebuild the other module (i.e. `hugeModule` and `module1`) eventhough there may be changes on those modules.

I tried:
`./gradlew :app:installDebug -a` which will not rebuild all dependencies. But I need to rebuild the `module2`.

I also tried running `./gradlew :module2:assembleDebug -a` and then `./gradlew :app:installDebug -a` which is working fine but it will configure gradle task twice.

Trying `./gradlew installDebug -a -b module2/build.gradle` also did not work since it's only building the `module2`.

Is there a way where I can make APK but specify which module get rebuild?

Comment: post your gradle files

Comment: What information you need to know from gradle files?

Comment: Forgot to mention @MarcinOrlowski